# How do I create a cube effect for PDF presentation transitions?

Tags: pdf, 3d, presentation, cube

I already saw in the past some presentations made with a 'cube effect' transition, similar to the 3D-multiple desktop of Compiz. I heard 'Keynotes' on Mac OSX could do that.

Is it possible to do the same on Ubuntu with PDF presentations? I tried **pdfcube** but it did not really kept its promises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is now possible in LibreOffice Impress to set the transition of a presentation to "Outside turning cube". Checked on LibreOffice 3.4.5 or greater.

This requires that the 3d-transitions be installed.

Answer (score 2):

I think it might have helped to tell us what packages you've already tried, so we're not duplicating bad suggestions...

But perhaps you want either [pdfcube](http://code.100allora.it/pdfcube) or [Impressive](http://impressive.sourceforge.net/)? (There was also another form of keyjnote called Accentuate, but the website for that seems to be down. I think there was some copyright issue with Apple with keyjnote.)

But word to the wise: I think such transitions are nothing but distractions to the content of your presentation, and can come off a little childish. The [LaTeX beamer user's guide](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/beamer/doc/beameruserguide.pdf) contains a ton of advice on how to create effective presentations, even if you're not using beamer to create these presentations, I think it's worth reading the first half of the guide.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but I'll stick to my first intention. Impressive is quite good but does not propose the original cube effect.